# How to run only specific task within a Job in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I have a job in Rundeck with many tasks within, but when some task fails I have to duplicate de Job, remove all the other tasks, save it and then run this new reduced copy of my original job.

Is there a way to run only specific tasks without having to do all this workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do that.

As a workaround, you can simply add `options` for every step in your Rundeck job, so for instances, if you have 3 script steps in your job, you can add 3 options named: `skip_step_1`, `skip_step_2` and `skip_test_3` and then assign `true` to the ones that have finished successfully and `false` to the one that has failed in the first execution. And for every script step, you can add a condition whether to run it or not.

A smiliar feature request is already proposed to the rundeck team :
[Optionally execute workflow step based on job options](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/916)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There should be an easier straightforward way to do that. Most of my steps are not scripts but plugins developed in-house. 